# AWS Cloudtrail Event for S3 Bucket in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, aws-code-deploy, amazon-cloudtrail

I had quite a hard time setting up an automization with Beanstalk and Codepipeline...

I finally got it running, the main issue was the S3 Cloudwatch event to trigger the start of the `Codepipeline`. I missed the Cloudtrail part which is necessary and I couldn't find that in any documentation.

So the current Setup is:
S3 file gets uploaded -> a CloudWatch Event triggers the Codepipeline -> Codepipeline deploys to ElasticBeanstalk env.

As I said to get the CloudWatch Event trigger you need a `Cloudtrail` trail like:

```
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...
  name = "codepipeline-source-trail" #"codepipeline-${var.project_name}-trail"
  is_multi_region_trail = true
  s3_bucket_name = "codepipeline-cloudtrail-placeholder-bucket-eu-west-1"
  event_selector {
    read_write_type           = "WriteOnly"
    include_management_events = true

    data_resource {
      type = "AWS::S3::Object"

      values = ["${data.aws_s3_bucket.bamboo-deploy-bucket.arn}/${var.project_name}/file.zip"]
    }
  }
}
```

But this is only to create a new trail. The problem is that AWS only allows 5 trails max. On the `AWS console` you can add multiple data events to one trail, but I couldn't manage to do this in terraform. I tried to use the same name, but this just raises an error

> "Error creating CloudTrail: TrailAlreadyExistsException: Trail codepipeline-source-trail already exists for customer: XXXX"

I tried my best to explain my problem.  Not sure if it is understandable.
In a nutshell: I want to add a `data events:S3` in an existing cloudtrail trail with terraform.

Thx for help,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

> As I said to get the CloudWatch Event trigger you need a Cloudtrail trail like:

You do not need multiple `CloudTrail` to invoke a CloudWatch Event. You can create service-specific rules as well.

[Create a CloudWatch Events rule for an Amazon S3 source (console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/create-cloudtrail-S3-source-console.html)

From `CloudWatch` event rule to invoke `CodePipeline` as a target. Let's say you created this event rule

```json
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ]
  }
}
```

You add `CodePipeline` as a target for this rule and eventually, Codepipeline deploys to ElasticBeanstalk env.

Comment: Thx for your fast response, that was exactly the problem i faced :) Withouth the cloudtrail part the event will not get triggered, as it relies on the logging for S3. So you need both to have the final trigger work!

Comment: Maybe a workaround would be to have only one cloudtrail trail on the entire S3 Bucekt and the Cloudwatch event on the specific file...

Comment: @can-I-do you just need one cloudtrail enabled, not multiple.  In general always have one cloudtrail and then use that for catching API calls via CloudWatch.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add multiple data_resources to your current trail instead of adding a new trail with the same name:

```
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...
  name = "codepipeline-source-trail" #"codepipeline-${var.project_name}-trail"
  is_multi_region_trail = true
  s3_bucket_name = "codepipeline-cloudtrail-placeholder-bucket-eu-west-1"
  event_selector {
    read_write_type           = "WriteOnly"
    include_management_events = true

    data_resource {
      type = "AWS::S3::Object"

      values = ["${data.aws_s3_bucket.bamboo-deploy-bucket.arn}/${var.project_A}/file.zip"]
    }

    data_resource {
      type = "AWS::S3::Object"

      values = ["${data.aws_s3_bucket.bamboo-deploy-bucket.arn}/${var.project_B}/fileB.zip"]
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to add up to 250 data resources (across all event selectors in a trail), and up to 5 event selectors to your current trail ([CloudTrail quota limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/WhatIsCloudTrail-Limits.html))

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. Yes,  I guess that would be possible. The problem here is that you still create a new Trail every time you deploy a new stack. I could modify the terraform files to add multiple beanstalks and codepipelines and than just add a data resource everytime. but if you deploy one stack for each project at a time you can not add  another data source to an existing trail...

Comment: As I wrote in the other comment, maybe the only way is to create a cloudtrail trail for the entire bucket and than go more spefic in multiple cloudwatch events for each file.

Comment: Yeah, explore the second option where you have a dedicated trail for your beanstalks and then play around with the filters on the Event Rule. 

If there is no way to filter the data you need (as you go a bit deep to the exact file that you upload), you may want to take a look of an option where you have:
Dedicated trail —> CW Event —> triggers a Lambda with some logic to parse which file it was —> Lambda triggers the Pipeline in question based on the filename key.

Comment: Hm it still feels so wrong :) But I guess I do just create one trail "log all S3 Buckets and all Events" and than create Cloudwatch Event specified on each file which will trigger different codepipelines... thx for your help!